# John got a new dog?

Tags: cipher, visual

I was walking down the road the other day when I bumped into my old army friend John.

He had a new dog with him so I asked him what its name was.

Now he's a big nerd of all sorts of TV shows and films but he also loves his puzzles, so instead of telling me the dogs name he said something about getting even with me and handed me a piece of paper:

> [image]

I'm not sure what I did to him but it's been bugging me for a while now so I would appreciate it if someone could just tell me what the dog is called!

Hint:

> There is already multiple hints!

Hint 2:

> Both me and John spent time in a POW camp.

Hint 3:

> "J-A-Y? You're spelling Jay."
>  "As in Jay Garrick? He's he's alive."
>  "But he's on my Earth."
>  "Hey, hey Stop, stop hey Stop look, I'm sorry."
>  "I don't know what you mean."
>  "Jay Garrick didn't come with us."

Hint 4:

> Focus on the numbers more than the colours.

Comment: The hex value of the colours from left to right: FF4C4C, FFE84C, FFFF4C, 88FF58, 4CFFFF, 4C70FF and FF4CFF

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil Thanks! i use inverted colors:)

Comment: Damn it. I'm 99% sure I have the solution but can't fully figure out all steps to get to it...

Comment: @RottersSlave You can post a partial solution with what you've figured out to help other people!

Comment: My first guess was that it's a shifted [tap/knock code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tap_code), but there's 6 numbers here instead of 5 :(. I'm wondering if there's another way to make it work, or another code we should be using. Hint 2 strongly points towards a POW communication code.

Comment: @BMS21 Is there a reason why the first six is between red and orange?

Comment: @Smartis Nope which maybe a hint depending on how you look at it

Comment: I was thinking Ubtna'f Urebrf, but I don't think Jay is not a character in that. Maybe a code in that show is the decryption?

Answer (score 1):

Since that appears to be the colors of the rainbow, my guess is

> Roy G Biv, for one of the common acronyms for remembering the colors of the rainbow.

Comment: Afraid not plus theres nothing about the numbers on this one

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Well, based off of the new hint, the answer clearly requires usage of the tap code. Good luck all.

### OLD INFO BELOW

Some thoughts (Partial answer?):

It's possible that

> John is John Pryor, a deceased WW2 POW. [He was in the news a while ago for a code he used during the war.](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-2317548/Code-letters-sent-home-British-PoW-WWII-help-Allies-revealed-70-years.html) The flaw in this is: John Pryor's code is used for messages. The John in this story never gives us a long message, just a piece of paper with some numbers on it. Also, John Pryor signaled a coded message by using numbers for the date instead of fully writing out the words (10 instead of October) and you don't really see this in the puzzle.

Thought about ciphers:

> There are a TON of encryption methods used in wartime, so I am not going to spend more time reading through them looking for the right cipher. Hint 2 seems to suggest a prisoner -> prisoner code, but I haven't had success in finding more of those. Tap code seems to be the only popularly discussed code.

Other thoughts:

> Maybe the spelling/grammar mistakes mean something? That could be why Hint 1 doesn't seem useful; "is" should be "are". It would seem obvious that the colors are relevant somehow, but I don't know what to do with them. Beastly Gerbil posted the Hex codes of the colors. Maybe someone can figure out the relevance.

Something probably completely useless:

> Metadata in the file states that the picture was "Created with the Wolfram Language".

Comment: There are a couple of things in here which might help out but not much sorry!